# Where has the "consecutive days visited" counter gone?

Tags: support, badges

I'm trying to find the figure somewhere on my profile so that I can track progress toward attendance badges; it used to be prominent on the account page. Where has it gone - and am I missing something?

Comment: It's still on your profile, switch from the Activity (default when you view your own profile) to [the Profile tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/599393/rainydaymatt?tab=profile) and it's at the bottom of the right-hand bar.

Comment: You can also manually track the attendance badges with the track the next badge feature on your activity tab.

Answer (score 13):

It's still on the profile page, but you need to switch from the Activity tab (which is the default when you visit your own profile) to [the Profile tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599393/rainydaymatt?tab=profile). You can then see the counter at the bottom of the right-hand bar.

[image: Consecutive days counter on Profile page]

...yes, I know I have a problem.

Comment: 632 consecutive days.  That's... impressive.

Comment: Nah, you don't. [This guy does](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iqPoc.png) (and no, that's not me)

Comment: Actually that can't be right, because that's exactly how long I've been a member. I can't have visited every day for 20 months... right? And wow @Martijn that's at once terrifying and a little bit impressive!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that is exactly right; you've been active every single day but one since you joined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that doesn't make sense, how can I have been inactive for one day, but without breaking the streak? The day I joined?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: click on the line, and a calendar pops up. Every day you were recorded as active is coloured green. What is activity is enough to be counted 'active' is secret, simply logging in is not enough.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Active on day 1.  Inactive on day 2.  Active the rest of the time.  That only counts days visited, not days since account creation.

Comment: @ryanyuyu ah, I see, that makes sense! Indeed, checking the calendar, I was (only!) inactive on the 18th of November, 2013. I wonder if I was doing anything interesting?